# Replace <div> tag with <br> on keydown in chrome for HTML contenteditable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am not able to replace the div tag with br tag on keypress in google chrome. When you press enter Google chrome reads it as div tag but i want to make it work as br tag. Please suggest the solution.

I have tried this:

```
$("#condition_pop").keypress(
   function { 
     if (e.which == 13) { 
           e.preventDefault(); 
           document.selection.createRange().pasteHTML("<br/>"); 
 } })
```

Comment: $("#condition_pop").keypress(function  {
    if (e.which == 13) {
     e.preventDefault();
     document.selection.createRange().pasteHTML("<br/>");
    }
   });

Comment: I am using a content editable div in my project. When i press enter in the div, enter is considered as "<div>" tag while i want it to be "<br>" tag. This code works in IE and mozilla firefox but as Keypress event does not work in chrome i am trying to replace "<div>" with "<br>" as above code. But this is not working for me. can you please provide a solution for the same.

Comment: @ShrikantVenne edit question with what have you tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using the below function to replace the `<div>` tag with `<br>`

```
$(function($){ 
$.fn.editableContent = function() 
    { 
        return this.html().replace(/<div>/gi,'<br>').replace(/<\/div>/gi,''); 
    }; 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a cross-browsers method to catch the ENTER key:

```
$('#condition_pop').keydown( function(e) {
    var key = e.charCode ? e.charCode : e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : 0;
    if(key == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("enter pressed");
    }
});
```

Tested on Chrome 24 : http://jsfiddle.net/PTauw/1/

Comment: How can i replace "<div>" tag with "<br>" tag when pressed enter in google chrome ?

Comment: No its a "div" section within Window.open

Comment: Sorry but your question is not clear. You could check replaceWith function : http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/

Comment: i am using the below function to replace the <br> tag with <div>

`$(function($){
    $.fn.editableContent = function() {
        return this.html().replace(/<div>/gi,'<br>').replace(/<\/div>/gi,'');   
    };
});`